# Counting with rule of of sum differs from number of selections obtained by the combination formula.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am counting the number of ways to select $4$ cards from a suit of $13$. The combination formula gives me:

${13 \choose 4}= 715$ ways to do it.

I was looking for coming to that number by using the rule of sum. Here's my attempt:

Suppose the cards are represented by the thirteen letters: $\{A, B, ... , M\}$

Let's call $\{A, B, C, D\}$ the pivot selection. We will obtain all other combinations by mutating the pivot. To get a unique combination, I can choose to drop one, two three or all four of the cards and replace them with cards chosen from $9$ that aren't part of the pivot.

There are ${4 \choose 1}$ ways to select one card to drop from the pivot. For each three-card collection that we obtain by dropping one card from the pivot, we have ${9 \choose 1}$ options for replacing the dropped card. Hence, the number of combinations that are possible by replacing one card from the pivot is

$${4 \choose 1} \times {9 \choose 1} = 36$$

Similarly, we can obtain ${4 \choose 2} \times {9 \choose 2} = 216$ combinations by replacing two cards, ${4 \choose 3} \times {9 \choose 3} = 336$ combinations by replacing three cards, and ${4 \choose 4} \times {9 \choose 4} = 126$ combinations by replacing all four cards.

Adding these numbers should give me the number of ways we can combine 4 cards from a set of $13$ cards. But,

$$36 + 216 + 336 + 126 = 714 \ne {13 \choose 4} = 715$$ Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If I'm reading your work correctly, you forgot to account that the pivot selection itself has to be counted as well(dropping zero cards), which adds one to your answer.

Comment: @AidenChow I see. For some reason I thought that I was covering the no replacement case with ${4 \choose 4} \times {9 \choose 4}$. Silly me :)